# iOS how to know that autocorrect or predictive typing is about to replace text in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, autocorrect

I'm attempting to create a remote typing app, where a person typing into one text view would see the same text appear in remote text view. For simple keystrokes, like "A" or "B, I'm sending them to remote service in sequence.

However, when autocorrect is enabled, it is possible that the text field or text view will replace them with the correction or suggestion **after the user presses space**. For example:

```
"T-e-s-a " might be replaced with Tess or Test.
```

This would cause my remote field to say "TesaTess ". I want to detect this condition and fix it.

**How would I detect if autocorrect will replace some text with the corrected string?**

Currently I'm using this method to handle cursor movement on the screen. Would I have to modify this method to account for the change, or is there an easier way?

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

    NSRange r = textView.selectedRange;

    if(r.length == 0)
    {
        /*
         Cursor moved using magnifying glass
         */

    }else{
        //the user selected some text  
        NSLog(@"Selected From: %lu length: %lu", r.location, r.length); // end position in text selection

    }

}
```

Comment: I was able to catch all autocorrected text via using both `textViewDidEndEditing` + `textViewDidChange` methods. It isn't perfect solution but it works for perfomance non-critical textViews with small amount of text.